# How to draw an empty plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I need to make an empty plot. This is the best could I come up with.

```
plot(0, xaxt = 'n', yaxt = 'n', bty = 'n', pch = '', ylab = '', xlab = '')
```

Any simpler solutions?

P.S.: completely empty, no axis etc.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

How about something like:

```
plot.new()
```

Comment: @Adam `x11()` is a cross-platform R command to open a new device.  If you have a device open and call `plot.new()`, the current device will be cleared.

Comment: Is there an advantage to `x11()` over `dev.new()`?  My instinct is to go with the latter to accommodate whatever the local default device is, but I'm not certain that's how things work.

Comment: @Matt: I use `x11()` due to habit.  I'm no expert on plotting in R but after glancing at the documentation, `dev.new()` would probably be better.

Comment: @Matt & Joshua, plot.new() is better for my needs. I wanted the empty plot to serve as filler in a multiplot (mfrow) plot. dev.new() doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Ah, now I see - thought you needed to call a dev.new() before plot.new(), but that's unnecessary.  Subtle differences - it's nice to know about both.

Answer (score 89):

I suggest that someone needs to make empty plot in order to add some graphics on it later. So, using

```
plot(1, type="n", xlab="", ylab="", xlim=c(0, 10), ylim=c(0, 10))
```

you can specify the axes limits of your graphic.

Answer (score 42):

The following does not plot anything in the plot and it will remain empty.

```r
plot(NULL, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=c(0,1), ylab="y label", xlab="x lablel")
```

Which will produce:

[image]

This is useful when you want to add lines or dots afterwards within a `for` loop or something similar. Just remember to change the `xlim` and `ylim` values based on the data you want to plot.

**As a side note:**
This can also be used for Boxplot, Violin plots and swarm plots. for those remember to add `add = TRUE` to their plotting function and also specify `at =` to specify on which number you want to plot them (default is x axis unless you have set `horz = TRUE` in these functions.

If you want to trigger a new plot, for example when you are using `layout()`, you are better off with `plot.new()`. For example in the following we are adding empty plots to either side of the first row to add some padding:

```r
layout(mat = matrix(c(1,2,2,3,
                      4,4,5,5),
                    nrow = 2,
                    byrow = TRUE))
plot.new()
plot(iris[, 1:2])
plot.new()
plot(iris[, 1:2])
plot(iris[, 1:2])
```

In this plot I have manually annotated the regions to clarify what I mean:

[image]

And the following is what you actually get:

[image]

Answer (score 28):

This is marginally simpler than your original solution:

```
plot(0,type='n',axes=FALSE,ann=FALSE)
```

Comment: No need to add `ann=FALSE`, will anyway be an empty area. But a great solution, thanks!

Answer (score 17):

Adam, following your comment above ("I wanted the empty plot to serve as filler in a multiplot (mfrow) plot."), what you actually want is the mfg option

```
    par(mfg=c(row,column))
```

- which controls where you want to put the next plot. For instance, to put a plot in the middle of a 3x3 multiplot, do

```
    par(mfrow=c(3,3))
    par(mfg=c(2,2))
    plot(rnorm(10))
```

Answer (score 15):

You need a new plot window, and also a coordinate system, so you need `plot.new()` and `plot.window()`, then you can start to add graph elements:

```
plot.new( )
plot.window( xlim=c(-5,5), ylim=c(-5,5) )

points( rnorm(100), rnorm(100) )
axis( side=1 )
```

[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XV2EM.png)

Answer (score 4):

There is an interest in your solution that `plot.new()` hasn't though: in the empty plot you "draw" you can write text at specified coordinates with `text(x = ..., y = ..., your_text)`.

Answer (score 2):

```
grid.newpage() ## If you're using ggplot

grid() ## If you just want to activate the device.
```

Comment: `grid()` is unrelated to the grid package AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

An empty plot with some texts which are set position.

```
plot(1:10, 1:10,xaxt="n",yaxt="n",bty="n",pch="",ylab="",xlab="", main="", sub="")
mtext("eee", side = 3, line = -0.3, adj = 0.5)
text(5, 10.4, "ddd")
text(5, 7, "ccc")
```

Comment: Why add text? What does that have to do with "How to create an empty plot?". Overall, this seems more complicated than OP's method in the question, `plot(0,xaxt='n',yaxt='n',bty='n',pch='',ylab='',xlab='')`, since you add `main = "", sub = ""` even you get the same result without them.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a `ggplot2` solution, you can use either [`cowplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/introduction.html) or [`patchwork`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) packages

```r
library(ggplot2)

### examples from cowplot vignettes
plot.mpg <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = cty, y = hwy, colour = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5)
plot.diamonds <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0.5))

library(cowplot)
### use NULL
plot_grid(plot.mpg, NULL, NULL, plot.diamonds,
  labels = c("A", "B", "C", "D"),
  ncol = 2
)

# Note: if you want to initialize an empty drawing canvas, use ggdraw()
```

[image]

```r
library(patchwork)
### use plot_spacer()
plot.mpg + plot_spacer() + plot_spacer() + plot.diamonds +
  plot_layout(ncol = 2) +
  plot_annotation(
    title = "Plot title",
    subtitle = "Plot subtitle",
    tag_levels = "A",
    tag_suffix = ")"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another simple `ggplot2` option is using [geom_blank](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_blank.html) like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_blank()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see the plot is blank.